# Getting free design for a hobbyist project

Tags: designers

I created a small device for myself that has a scale I painted on it over time. I want to create a small sticker on it that makes it look better. Nothing fancy. Now I noticed that this is actually not easy graphics-design-wise, to make it look "from one source".
Given that it's a hobbyist project and this is the only version, I am wondering where I get this designed for free.

Here is a picture of the current situation:

[image]

Comment: The same place where you get food for free.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for free work

Comment: I have attempted to alter the nature of the "request."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because free work req

Comment: Come on @BrutusCruciatus, don't take it that way. Your question is just out of place on this site. People here are very generous with help and advice for amateurs and hobbyists , but asking for free work is not accepted since it will not help others with the same problem. It is also kind of disrespectful because people here are either professionals trying to make a living on graphic design or dedicated amateurs who are willing to spend many hours trying to learn themselves.

Comment: Every request for help on this site is a request for unpaid work. <rant> I objected to "professionals" here giving explicit answers to school assignments where the "student" paid nothing in return for the request—and got nothing—no practice, no experience, no challenge, nothing. I think that's worse than a truthful request for help on a project outside the ability and budget of a hobbyist. </rant> Disclaimer: I **Invited** the "guest" from another hostile audience on stackexchange for a more hospitable welcome. Truthfully, I feel bad about this experience. I'm embarrassed and feel sorry

Comment: @Stan, I didn't want Brutus to loose faith in humanity. I should have turned down the sarcasm in my first comment and I apologize for that. I just went through a day with customers trying to make me work for free and was feeling sad that people are willing to pay for all sorts of physical products for their hobby, but not the work I'm able to do. But we must try to keep GDSE free from requests for free work, because it will ruin the site in the long run. Every request should be a request for unpaid _education_ - not unpaid _execution_.

Comment: @Wolff I understand and after re-reading the Help Centre myself agree. I don't think I could agree with your last statement more. You understand that's what I attempted to do by re-working the question and answering Brutus' edited question as instructions, a "How-To." I'm sensitive to "attitude" from my colleagues which is the reason for my rant. Maybe I should increase my dosage.

Answer (score 3):

There are two parts to this "question."

You ask for a design to be done; but, the design is already done and, from what you say, it is functional.

That brings us to the "doing" of the design. Let's call that the "build" part of the "design-build" process.

- Wash your hands and find a well-lit, clean, clutter-free workspace.
- Remove your prototype and place it on a sheet of clean paper. Use some masking tape to hold it in place temporarily.
- Use a pin-hole to locate the centre of your intended opening. Be as accurate as you can.
- Put a pin-hole on each of the radiating index lines of your prototype. Be as accurate as you can.
- Lightly, draw a faint, rough circle with a pencil where the opening appears
- Remove the prototype from the paper "template" base.
- With a pen draw lines from the centre pin-hole outward to the pin-holes for each of the index lines. (3, 4, 5, 6, etc. to 30)
- Fold the paper in half through the centre pin hole and cut a hole with a pair of scissors to make a clean hole in the centre of your template.
- Flatten the template and glue some cut numbers in their proper position for each index mark around the aperture.

At this point, the template is finished and can be cut to the proper size and positioned on your device. If you want something even cleaner, photocopy the template onto self-adhesive or regular paper stock. Cut the aperture and then the template.

- Done

Good luck.